# Prevent HTML5 Web App From Restart

Tags: html, ios6

Everytime I switch back to my Web App in iOS6 it starts from the landing page. I need it to be like safari where it retains its current page.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you need to save any variables in whatever storage you use then when the web app is loaded, load those variables. It's painful, but its the only way I know of.